# Реализация OAuth2.0 C++ Linux

Tags: c++, linux, oauth2

Кто знает/может подсказать реализации для OAuth 2.0 на C++. Хотелось бы с примерами кода. Принимаются также варианты и на Си, а также в виде исключения и oauth.

Answer (score 1):

Гуглить пробовали? Есть множество реализаций различной сложности. Например:

- https://github.com/sirikata/liboauthcpp
- https://google.github.io/google-api-cpp-client/latest/guide/oauth2.html
- https://github.com/pipacs/o2 (для Qt)

Comment: Гуглить пробовал. Все что нагуглил - это liboauthcpp. Если это `множество`, то странное о нем у Вас понятие. И разве судя по вопросу я хотел ограничиться Google API? В общем и целом хотелось бы увидеть ответы практиков.

Comment: я в свое время использовал https://github.com/pipacs/o2  - вполне себе работало. Правда это не чистый с++ - это для Qt.

Comment: не знаю, к сожалению или к счастью, но мне не удалось подружиться с QT, как я этого не желал. Пробовал и под Win и под Lin, но отношения не срослись. Но ссылочка пусть остается. Не мне одному может быть это интересно в последствие.

Comment: а на чем вы тогда рисуете окошки в линуксах на с++ если с кутэ не срослось?

Comment: @eri Ну так есть же обычная GTK. Непосредственно для компоновки использую glade. На комент ответил так "быстро", потому что кто-то не умеет пользоваться справкой и свои коменты постит в тучу. Случайно просматривал старые свои вопросы (вдруг вот так вот что-то изменилось) и увидел данный комент.

Comment: @MaxZS gtk на плюсах - звучит костыльно. попробуйте vala

Comment: @eri для меня gui в моих проектах второстепенно. Поэтому мне gtk более чем достаточно. Что касается отдельного языка программирования - то это уже черезчур... Если мне нужно что-то еще проще в написании, то открываю монодевелоп и юзаю C#  с тем же gtk (точнее gtk#). В монодевелоп и glade не нужен - там есть свой редактор окошечек.